# Can you host a blazor app on IIS in a sub folder?

Tags: c#, iis, hosting, blazor

I have the basic blazor project that im trying to host in a specific way. I have managed to host the app in IIS where all the files were in the same folder. **The issue im having is the web config in the root folder and then having the actual app itself in a subfolder.**

[IIS app file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpeYP.png)

im using blazor server which is sitting the "test" folder.

[test folder where the blazor app is, seperate to the web config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJl0C.png)

Is this even possible to host in this way? or is there routing or config that needs to be done to get it to work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

So far I'm afraid it is unavailable to host application in site level. No matter I set the aspnet core handler in root level or folder level, change location value,change processPath. IIS just ignore the attribute even I have set it in both root level and folder level.

[image]

I think even you were able to host blazor in a sub-folder, Duplicate attribute verification is easy to crash the application when you need to publish something in root folder.

So the best way to handle this is convert test folder to an application. Then everything get isolated and start working.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

interesting idea
I see no reason, why not to create a sub directory as website in iis. There have to be a extra app pool unmanaged for each.